# ASP.NET MVC - jQuery POST method is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm calling a `PartialView` and injected it to a `<div>` from another `PartialView` to make it popup modal using `Boostrap Modal`.
So far, my Boostrap Modal is displaying as expected BUT, NOT behaving as expected. The following are my objectives in my Boostrap Modal.

1. Make a Boostrap Modal - **OK**
2. Add validation on the Boostrap Modal - **OK**
3. Send the value of my modal to save in the database - **NOT OK**

**This is the `<div>` where I inject the `PartialView` and make it a modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create Sample</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="modalBodyContainer">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnCreateSample">Create</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**PartialView to show as Boostrap Modal (This will be injected in the above `<div>`)**

```
@model WebSensoryMvc.Models.SampleData

 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "SessionData", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FormCreateSample", name = "FormCreateSample" }))
 {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="container">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GroupNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GroupNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GroupNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MaterialID, "Material", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("MaterialID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MaterialID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SampleCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SampleCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SampleCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BatchCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BatchCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control text-uppercase" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BatchCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SizeID, "Size", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("SizeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SizeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AgeID, "Age", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("AgeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AgeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TemperatureID, "Temperature", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("TemperatureID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TemperatureID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PackagingTypeID, "Packaging Type", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("PackagingTypeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PackagingTypeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Spike, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Spike)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Spike, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SampleType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SampleType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SampleType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Remarks, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Remarks, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Remarks, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 }
```

Currently, I'm having hard time debugging in saving the modal value in the database. I'm using `ajax` to call a method in a controller. But, I'm experiencing the following problems.

1. When the below code is executed, the `$('#FormCreateSample').serialize()` which expected to return the model of the `PartialView` is blank, where all the properties are null.

   ```
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnModal").on('click', function () {
       var url = "/SessionData/Create";

       $.ajax({
           url: url,
           type: 'GET',
           success: function (data) {
               $('#modalBodyContainer').html(data)
               $('#myModal').modal('show');

               $("#btnCreateSample").off().on('click', function () {

                   var form = $('form');

                   form.data('validator', null);
                   $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);

                   if ($('form').valid()) {

                       $.ajax({
                           url: "/SessionData/Create",
                           type: "POST",
                           data: $('#FormCreateSample').serialize(),
                           success: function () {
                               alert("POST success");
                           },
                           error: function () {
                               alert("POST error");
                           }
                       });

                   }
               });
           }
       });
   });
    });
   ```
2. Since my action method in controller have `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` annotation, the above script throw an exception **"Token is not present..."**. To fix that, I updated my code and add the below lines of code.

   ```
    var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
     $.ajax({
        url: "/SessionData/Create",
        type: "POST",
        data: { $('#FormCreateSample').serialize(), __RequestVerificationToken: token },
       success: function () {
          alert("POST success");
       },
       error: function () {
           alert("POST error");
       }
    });
   ```

The problem in # 2 approach is, it passes `null` value in my action method `sampleData` parameter. Below is my action method in my controller.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public void Create(SampleData sampleData)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            sampleData.SessionID = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["CurrentSessionId"]);

            db.SampleDatas.Add(sampleData);
            db.SaveChanges();

            RedirectToAction("List", "SessionData");
        }

    }
```

Anyone have an idea why `$("FormCreateSample").serialize()` is `null`? Or maybe it cannot find the form id **FormCreateSample**?

TIA

**UPDATE 1**
After using the first answer, the model is now pass to method but all properties are still `null`.

[image]

Comment: `.serialize()` will include the token. There is no need to add it again. Show your model (does it have properties with getters/setters or just fields?

Comment: I also assume its really `public ActionResult Create(SampleData sampleData)`(not `void`)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke

My model has a getters/setters and I'm using EF. I'm not also sure but I can use `RedirectToAction` rather `ActionResult` since I'm not returning my current view which is a `PartialView`. But I can test that also.

Comment: No, I mean the signature of the method needs to be `ActionResult` not `void`

Comment: @StephenMuecke

If I understand correctly, you need `ActionResult` as your signature in your method if you want to return the corresponding view of your method. Since my `Create` method correspond to a `PartialView` who is a modal, there is no point to return that view. That's why I rather use `RedirectToAction` signature to redirect after saving my data to database.

Comment: Your not using 'RedirectToAction' signature - your using `void`! `ActionResult` is a base class and you can return anything that inherits from it including `ViewResult`, `PartialViewResult`, `RedirectResult` etc. (`void` does not return anything). And I repeat again. `.serialize()` serializes everything in the form including the token (and if you use add `console.log($('#FormCreateSample').serialize());` and inspect the result you will see it.

Comment: Oh yes sorry my bad. I'm not using `RedirectToAction` as signature since I use `void`. I'll try again your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121898/discussion-between-klaydze-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: why you are not using `Ajax.BeginForm` ?

Comment: Change var form = $('form'); to $("#FormCreateSample") Alternatively you can use var formData = new FormData($("#FormCreateSample"));

Answer (score 1):

You need to add AntiForgeryToken in your message header in the ajax call:

```
var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
var tokenadr = $('form[action="/SessionData/Create"] input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val(); 

var headers = {};
var headersadr = {};
headers['__RequestVerificationToken'] = token;
headersadr['__RequestVerificationToken'] = tokenadr;

 $.ajax({
 url: "/SessionData/Create",
 type: "POST",
 headers: headersadr,
 data: "__RequestVerificationToken=" + token + "" + $('form[action="/SessionData/Create"]').serialize(),
success: function () {
   alert("POST success");
},
error: function () {
    alert("POST error");
}
});
```

Comment: Hi @Singh,

It passes the model now in the method but still all properties are `null`.
Please see updated original message. I have attached a snip for reference. 

Thanks

Comment: Why not you send data in stringify in string format.

Comment: you can check your data before you pass in params

Comment: Caling `alert(JSON.stringify($('#FormCreateSample')));` returns `{}`. Looks like `$('#FormCreateSample')` cannot be found?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
.serialize()
```

To

```
.serializeArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
  $.ajax({
     url: "/SessionData/Create",
     type: "POST",
     data: { $('#FormCreateSample').serialize(), __RequestVerificationToken: token },
     content-type : 'application/json',
    success: function () {
       alert("POST success");
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("POST error");
    }
 });
```

**ADD this :  content-type : 'application/json',**

Answer (score 0):

After couple of days in debugging my scenario, I found my solution now. Instead of using `Bootstrap Modal`, I use `Bootbox`. Using `Bootbox` fixed all my problems from validation up to saving to database.

Below is the script that I use to open a modal.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#modalCreateSample").on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/SessionData/Create",
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {

                bootbox.dialog({
                    title: "Create Session",
                    message: data,
                    buttons: {
                        success: {
                            label: "Save",
                            className: "btn-success",
                            callback: function () {

                                var form = $('#FormCreateSample');
                                form.data('validator', null);
                                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);

                                if ($(form).valid()) {
                                    $.post("/SessionData/Create", $("#FormCreateSample").serialize(), function (data, status) {
                                        if (status == "success") {
                                            // Refresh list of samples

                                            return false;
                                        }
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

            },
            error: function (error) {
                bootbox.alert("We encounter problem while retrieving the Sample Code of the selected Session");
            }
        });
    });
});
 </script>
```